# How do I include generic secrets/config file in github repository (for CI purposes) without deploying it to production

Tags: python, git, github, travis-ci, api-key

I'm using some APIs in my application that require API keys. I added a secrets file for my local computer with a test API key and also added a secrets file to production with the production API key. I added the secrets file to gitignore and it is not included with my github repository.

However, Travis-CI fails its build when I don't have a secrets file in the github repository because it is unable to load the environment with that file missing.

How can I include a generic secrets file with a test key in the repository to pass Travis-CI builds as well as provide guidance to other developers on the filestructure but not have that generic secrets file deploy to production?

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods available according to the travis documentation.

On the one hand, you can encrypt information to include in the `.travis.yml` as described [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/) using public key crypto.

On the other hand, there is also a way to encrypt whole files as described [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/).